# The limits of plagiarism

Tags: journals, plagiarism, books, translations

Suppose I write an introductory article to a subject into a journal and I use ideas from a textbook in another language. The paper is not a translation of the book chapter but clearly relies on it. I cite that book.

What does count as plagiarism and what doesn't? What are the limits here?

Following the exposition does?

Comment: Do you have an a answer for the case where both languages are the same? I cannot see a difference.

Comment: I do not but this is my use case so I mentioned it.

Answer (score 3):

Plagiarism is taking the ideas of others and presenting them as your own, whether in their own words or not. By citing the other work you avoid plagiarism, but not necessarily all problems. If you are doing a translation, of the other work, present it as such. I can't give advice on whether that is always valid and it might require some permission of the copyright holder of the earlier work. I suspect that it does, but copyright rules vary widely around the world and, in many places, are a bit more generous for academic work and research.

Even in a single language, quoting from another work, with proper citation, and paraphrasing the other work with citation avoids plagiarism. But there are limits that are usually a matter of civil law. The more you "use" the shakier the ground gets, but that is a copyright issue, not plagiarism.

But if it is clear what is your own and what is adopted/adapted from another, you at least avoid plagiarism.

Comment: Why was that downvoted? The response is quite correct. Especially translations or near-translations are more than a plagiarism issue, they may veer into copyright issues.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, few people explain their downvotes. But there are a few general topics here that attract downvotes, perhaps by those with fixed ideas, correct or not.

Comment: I did see nothing wrong with it, but maybe I have overlooked something. I thought at least this comment might get people thinking about this response.

Comment: -1 Plagiarism is about misattribution of the authorship of a creative work, including one's own work.

Comment: @Alexis, self plagiarism is normally treated in a different category. But do you know of a case in which A does a piece of work and claims it was done by B instead? I don't doubt there is a case or two but it would seem to be so rare that it is seldom considered. I'll stand by my definition. On this site we have a different tag [tag:self-plagiarism] for that situation. Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism